# How can I get vim to draw lines correctly for remote editing?

Tags: vim, ssh

I'm attempting to edit files on a remote system.  I've ssh'd to the system and I start editing with vim.

However, I notice that all the lines are drawing 2 lines above where they really exist in the file.  I assumed this was a problem I could fix by dropping my terminal settings to something simpler, but that didn't help.

My TERM variable was set to xterm-color.  I set it to vt100, but that didn't fix the line drawing issue.  I also noticed that this seems to be specific to vim.  emacs doesn't show the problem, and I haven't noticed any odd drawing artifacts in less, more or other paging tools.

Other specifics: I'm ssh-ing into the remote system from a Mac, using the Terminal.app.  The remote system is running Ubuntu 9.04.

I'm hoping there is something I just need to set in vim to get it to play nice.  If it allows me to keep syntax color highlighting, so much the better.

Comment: how about just set your term as "xterm"? also, check the "term" setting of your Terminal.app. the remote system might not understand what "xterm-color" is and then will behavior abnormally.

Answer (score 1):

Zhaojun's suggestion works.  Setting TERM=xterm is clearing things up.